# app crashes when I try to call dismissViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view which I call my method:

```
    Twitter *tweet = [[Twitter alloc] initWithNibName:@"Twitter" bundle:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:tweet animated:YES];
```

the viewcontroller is presented without any problem. Now when i try to call dismissviewcontroller in method of twitter view controller like :
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

the app crashed ?

Even though basic structure is right but Still app crashes ? Why is that so ?

Comment: please show us the code where you're calling the dismiss, and what is the console error.

Comment: Show us the `dealloc` method of the twitter class, please.

Comment: - (void)dealloc {
     [tweetTextView release];
      [label release];
    [entry release];
 //self.entry = nil;
 [iTunesButton release];
            [_engine release];
         [tweetTextField release];
         [classN release];
            [super dealloc];
}

Comment: many thanks Alexander. There was indeed problem with dealloc...

Comment: I'm writing this in a post so you can close the question.

Answer (score 2):

try: `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];` - this is because the modal view controller is presented by the controller that presents the twitter controller and it's one that needs to dismiss the modal controller (which is the twitter controller)

**UPDATE:**
If you're targeting iOS 5+ then use:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
//or
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

else if you want to maintain backward compatibility use:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
else
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:nil];
}
```

Comment: parentViewController is not availble on iOS 5.

Comment: Also call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];` should just dismiss the presented viewcontroller, even if it is called in the presented view controller it self.

Comment: [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: The logic in my answer is the same for presenting. For ios5+ use presentViewController:animated:completion:  insted of presentModalViewController:animated:. If that doesn't help check if your logic in viewWillDisappear: or viewDidUnload methods cause the crash

Answer (score 0):

You need to dimiss the view from the navigation controller. Try this:

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem often occurs when you're overreleasing something in your destructor (the `dealloc` method). The IB always adds code to release objects, but it doesn't look if it already exists.